# Hot(ish) Observable

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I need to have something in between hot and cold Observable. It should emit items when client subscribes and stops emission when client unsubscribes. But when client subscribes to the same `Observable` the remained items should be delivered. And the last thing is time in between items.

```
Observable<String> hotishObservable = createHotishObservable("a", "b", "c");
Disposable sub = hotishObservable.subscribe();
// emit "a"
// 1 second passed
// emit "b"
sub.dispose()
Disposable sub = hotishObservable.subscribe();
// emit "c"
```

The obvious solution is to extend `ObservableOnSubscribe` and handle `ObservableEmitter`:

```
class HotishSub implements ObservableOnSubscribe<String> {

    public HotishSub(String... items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) {
        if(isNotEmpty())
            emitter.onNext(nextItem);
            executor.schedule(this::handleNext, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        else
            emitter.onComplete();
    }

    private void handleNext(){
        //if emitter is not disposed and there're still items then emit it
    }
}

Observable<String> createHotishObservable(String... items){
  return Observable.create(new HotishSub(items));
}
```

Is there any better option?

It's needed for stream of messages from simplified chat bot. UI client code uses the same `Observable` to get stream of messages from bots and real users.

Comment: Could [`WorkQueueProcessor`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/WorkQueueProcessor.html) be of any help in your case?

Comment: This would require a custom `Subject` in RxJava. Why do you want this behavior?

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot use an intervening `Subject` or `Relay`? Re-subscribing would pick up where it left off, and you could simply pace the items emitted using `Observable.interval( 0, 1, SECONDS).zipWith( obs, (t, o) -> o).subscripe( ov -> subject.onNext( ov) );`

Comment: @akarnokd it's for stream of messages from simplified chat bot. UI client code consumes the same `Observable` for a bot and real users.

Comment: @BobDalgleish yeah, I also was thinking about `Relay`. But actually requirement is a bit more complicated. Like delays could be different for every item. Or emission should be even stopped at some items.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Flowable.generate` to do it.

```
  public static <T> Flowable<T> create(T... ts) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(ts));
    return Flowable.generate(() -> list, (l, e) -> {
      if (l.isEmpty()) {
        e.onComplete();
      } else {
        e.onNext(l.remove(0));
        if (!l.isEmpty()) {
          try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // you can use other way to delay it
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Then test it

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Flowable<String> ob = create("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
    Disposable d = ob.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribe(i -> System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + "\t" + i));
    Thread.sleep(2500);
    d.dispose();
    ob.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .blockingSubscribe(i -> System.err.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + "\t" + i));
  }
```

And output:

```
1520304164412   a // sys.out
1520304165413   b // sys.out
1520304166413   c // sys.out
1520304166928   d // sys.err
1520304167927   e // sys.err
```